How to disable public ingress access on GCP App Engine
In Google cloud Platform we have a VPC vpc-A which is connected to onprem and to one another VPC vpc-B in same project(host) through VPN tunnel the vpc-A acts as a transit vpc, we want to deploy app engine on VPC vpc-B and want to disable public ingress access on the app engine and it should  be accessible only through internal network from onprem, the app engine is in different project(service) and the vpc-B is shared with service project.
How to achieve this setup the app engine is in service project, we have tried to deploy the app engine on shared vpc vpc-B and restricted the ingress access of service to internal only but it's not reachable, any help would be appreciated.

With AppEngine standard, it's not possible. But you can set a firewall rules to avoid public traffic. If you use AppEngine flex, I'm not sure. But I'm sure you should use Cloud Run instead and with Cloud Run you can control easily the ingress. But..... The best solution, IMO, is not to care about the network, but to focus only on the identity and request an authorized credential to access your app, whatever the VPC, network and others!!!

Found this post:

At this time it is not possible to do this.
I suspect this limitation is because App Engine is not available for VPC Service Controls like other services as Cloud Run or Cloud Functions where a perimeter is needed to reach them, the ingress is internal (or internal + load balancer) and the service is not in the host project.
For now the workaround is to have the App Engine service in the host project.
On the other hand there is already a Feature Request to allow requests coming from a resource in a Shared VPC.

I’m not certain if this is possible with App Engine Flexible or other products but please refer to below setup guide:

App Engine Flexible:

Setting up the App Engine flexible environment with Shared VPC

Configure private internal-only services



Cloud Load Balancing:

Configure a load balancer with a cross-project backend service



